# Giving user permission to just 1 single directory

Tags: linux, ssh, permissions

I'm using debian on my home server. My goal is to create a user with permissions to upload files just in his directory `(/var/www/user)`. The user should be able to access his dir using SSH, but he shouldn't be able to see parent dirs. /var/www/user should be his root dir and he shouldn't be able to see /var/www. How I can restrict user permissions like that?

Comment: `My goal is to create a user with permissions to upload files just in his directory` are we talking about FTP or SCP ?

Comment: he's gonna upload via SSH (PSCP/PUTTY)

Comment: Debian ( see first sentence )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the following directive into /etc/ssh/sshd_config:

```
ChrootDirectory /var/www/%u
```

See `man sshd_config`.

Note that with this setting, the user won't be able to log into an interactive session, unless /var/www/user contains a complete shell environment (/bin/sh and so on).  But they will be able to use ssh/scp/sftp to transfer files into and out of just that directory.

The above will apply to all users.  To restrict it to just one user, add `Match User user` in sshd_config before `ChrootDirectory`.

Comment: Will this apply for all other users? I want to make this just for a single user

Comment: Yes this will apply to all users. To restrict to one user add `Match User myuser` in `sshd_config` and then add directive under like `ChrootDirectory /var/www/myuser`

Comment: Requires the directory to be owned by `root`, so it won't work with regular user homes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [jailkit](http://olivier.sessink.nl/jailkit/) can come in handy. This is a tool to set up a chroot environment for a user, providing only very specific executables while limiting access to a certain directory and its subdirectories.